# GetFirstDocTemplatePosition() returns NULL

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex, ocx

I have a MFC to display graph data. I created OCX for the same to display graph in another application. in Normal exe I have an right click pop up menu to do some operation. But when I use the OCX in another application, when I do right click application crash. I got the detail by debugging as follows,

```
POSITION  pos = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
// here GetFirstDocTemplatePosition() returns NULL so the below line crashes.
CDocTemplate* doc_template = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate(pos);
```

I couldn't understand why GetFirstDocTemplatePosition() returns NULL. I created separate MENU for exe and OCX. separate resource files too.
Eg:
My application is MyGraph then I created MyGraphOCX.sln for OCX and resource_ocx.h, MyGraphOCX.rc for OCX.

```
POSITION CWinApp::GetFirstDocTemplatePosition() const
{
    if (m_pDocManager == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return m_pDocManager->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
}
```

Here `m_pDocManager` is `NULL`. Why this is NULL I don't understand.

Please provide your valuable suggestions

Comment: Where Did you create your document templates? Show us the code.

Comment: This the document template for the main application, in which i'm trying to call OCX.

Comment: CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;

 pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
  IDR_MAINFRAME,
  RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyAppDoc),
  RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
  RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainAppView));
 if (!pDocTemplate)
  return FALSE;
 AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);